# how do i limit an attribute plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

so i have this code

`df.plot(kind="bar", x="Countries", y=["2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019"], figsize=(50,5), stacked= True, title="Persentase populasi yang terjangkau jaringan seluler")`

and this data[image]

if i want to limit the number of the country displayed, for example, the first 20 countries. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
df.iloc[:20].plot(kind="bar", x="Countries", y=["2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019"], figsize=(50,5), stacked= True, title="Persentase populasi yang terjangkau jaringan seluler")
```

With `df.iloc[:20]` you select first 20 rows from your DataFrame.